# "Both" vs "Both of" in case of passive voice

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, prepositional-verbs

I am confused with this sentence:

- ...So, **both of** the speech signal and envelops were shifted with the same amount

Should I use **both** or **both of** and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use "both" with two nouns or pronouns joined by "and," you don't say "both of." For example:

> **Both** Mike **and** I were excited to watch the game.

You use "both of" with a plural noun or pronoun:

> **Both of us** were excited to watch the game.

In your example, since you are using "and," you wouldn't say "both of."